# What is the function of と when it's not quoting, or doing exhaustive listing?

Tags: grammar, meaning, particle-と

Consider these two sentences:

> (1) 母はついてくるようにアリスに合図した (Mother signaled to Alice to follow her)
>
> (2) 父は手で私に部屋を出ていくように**`と`**合図した。 (Father gestured to me to go out of the room)

And another sentence which I suspect has the same use of と　as (2) but I cannot exactly say what it does:

> (3) この本は子供を対象**`と`**した本です。(Unnatural: This book is a book that is done in order for children to be targets) (Natural: This is a book for children)

Now I deconstruct the use of `AをBとC` in (3) to mean "Do verb C to achieve state B in direct object A"

**(Question)** How would I understand the use of `と` in (2)? Since (1) does not require `と` yet has a similar structure involving `ように`. But `XようにY` means "to do Y so that X can happen". What happens when `と` is added to the mix as in (2)?

(Example sentences taken from WWWJDIC)

Comment: Is this a question about 「と」+verb?

Comment: @Ignacio yes, and also about the apparent lack of difference when と is not used in the comparison of (1) and (2).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Francis Drohan's *A handbook of Japanese usage* has four whole pages on the usages of と, so I don't think a comprehensive answer is appropriate here. But a few key points:

- There are two kinds of と: one is a case particle (格助詞), and another is a conjunctive particle (接続助詞). In both your examples, と is being used as a case particle.
- According to Drohan, there are 7 main uses for the case particle と: Listing, accompaniment, target of comparison, result of change, adverbialisation, quotation, and simile.
- と in your example (2) is being used to denote quotation. ‘Father signalled to me with his hand, “get out of the room.”’
- と in your example (3) is being used to denote the result of change. (In fact, Drohan gives the following example: 学生を対象とする。 It is meant for students.) The construction 〜とする here has the connotation of a decision being made: the target audience was *set* to be students.

  Drohan gives some other examples of this usage:

  > 塵も積もれば山となる。 Many a little makes a mickle.
  >
  > 夜となく昼となく働く。 They work morning, noon and night.
- However, the collocation 〜とする also has other uses, e.g. 学生として ‘as a student’,　なかったとしたら ‘supposing there were none’, etc.

Comment: You are assuming that (at least) `部屋を出てくように` is a unit (constituent) because you are saying that it is a quotation (which part I do not agree), and that the `と` following it is a case particle. Doesn't that mean that `部屋を出てくように` is a noun?

Comment: @sawa: Not my analysis. But [Daijisen](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/srch/jn/%E3%81%A8/m0p2u/) agrees with Drohan, see sense 2 under heading 1: 「（文や句をそのまま受けて）動作・作用・状態の内容を表す。引用の「と」。」

Answer (score 6):

The `と` in (1, 2) is the same `と` as used in quoting. It leads a subordinate clause. Unlike predicates like `言う` 'say', which can take direct or indirect quotation, predicates like `合図する` 'signal' cannot take quotation. It expresses an accompanied message. Without `と`, it is ambiguous. It may be a purposive clause or a clause expressing the accompanied message.

> 母はついてくるようにアリスに合図した
>   'Mother signaled Alice to follow her'
>   'Mother signaled Alice so that she will follow her'

With `と`, it is unambiguously a clause expressing the accompanied message.

> 母はついてくるようにとアリスに合図した
>   'Mother signaled Alice to follow her'

The `と` in (3) is completely different. Note that the `と` in (3) is attached to a noun rather than a clause. In this sentence, the noun is the main predicate. When a noun is a predicate, it takes either `に` or `と`.

**Nominal predicate**

> 対象に/となる
>   対象である [Underlyingly `にてある`]
>   対象に/とする

Comment: As much as I like etymology, I wouldn't go so far as to say that で is _underlyingly_ にて, especially here where it cannot be substituted without raising eyebrows.

Comment: @Zhen As far as you assume that contraction from にて to で is obligatory, there is no wonder that it cannot be substituted. There are obligatory operations, and you do not deny them just because you cannot substitute the output with the input.

Comment: My point is that にて still exists in its own right, as a literary substitute for _locational_ uses of で. ‘Obligatory’ contraction sounds like a hack to me.

Comment: @Zhen I see. That is a good point.