# What is the grammatical function of と in the sentence 同じ心を持った人は二人といない

Tags: grammar, particles, polarity-items

What is the grammatical function of と in the sentence:

> 同じ心を持った人は二人**と**いない。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a less common but distinct function of と. When `number + counter + と` is combined with a negation, it means "(not) even". 明鏡国語辞典 第二版 says:

> #### と
>
> ⑧ 《少数量を表す語＋「と」の形で、下に打ち消しを伴って》事が成立しないことや持続しないことを強調していう。わずか…それだけなのに…ない。「何をやっても三日**と**続かない」「こんな所は五分**と**我慢できない」
>
> ⑨ 《二つの意を表す語＋「と」の形で、下に打ち消しを伴って》一つの意を強調していう。一つ［一度・一人…］だけだ。「命は二つ**と**ない」「こんな失敗は二度**と**しない」「こんな機会はまた**と**ない」

It may be better to memorize 二度と～ない, またとない and 二つとない as idioms.

Related: [The role of と particle in 「二度としない」](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/3052/5010)

Answer (score 2):

と　or として in this usage has the meaning "as much/many as" or "even"

so your sentence

> 同じ心を持った人は二人といない。

would mean something like:

There aren't **even** two people who feel/think the same way.

or

There aren't **even as many as** two people who feel/think the same.

or more naturally in English:

No two people think alike. (we simplify the idea of **not even two** into "no two")

Answer (score 1):

I am thinking 二人といない could mean "there's nobody else" or "there will never be another person", along the same lines as 二度と which means "never again".