# When is と added to onomatopoeia?

Tags: grammar, particle-と, onomatopoeia

While at first I believed it was simply bound to each individual word, I've noticed that the same onomatopoeic word sometimes has と after it and sometimes it doesn't.

Here's a case I stumbled upon:

> 踊り手は つま先立ってぐるぐると回った
>
> 犬が自分のしっぽを追いかけてぐるぐる回っている

What difference does the inclusion of と make?

Comment: It would be interesting to know if there is a rule but I concluded it was case by case, and in some cases the と was optional: If you look up the section on onomatopoeic words in the Dictionary Basic Japanese Grammar you will see that for number of words the と is in brackets.

Answer (score 15):

I am going to post a rather simplistic answer just covering the basics.

There are cases (1) where adding a 「と」 is **appropriate**, (2) where adding a 「と」 is  **inappropriate**, and (3) where only adding a 「**に**」, not a 「と」, is appropriate.

1) When an onomatopoeia functions adverbially to modify a verb, a 「と」 is often added.  In very informal speech, on the contrary, it is often omitted.

> 「ワンワン**と**[犬]{いぬ}が[鳴]{な}いている。」 = "A dog is barking 'bowwow'."
>
> 「[女]{おんな}はトウキョウナゴヤをゴツン**と**[殴]{なぐ}り、[部屋]{へや}を[出]{で}ていった。」= "The woman clonked TokyoNagoya in the head and ran out of the room."

2) When an onomatopoeia is used with the verb 「する」, it is **inappropriate** to add a 「と」.

> 「**ニコニコするなっ**！ここは[陸軍]{りくぐん}だ！マクドナルドじゃねえぞっ！」 = "Don't be smiling!  This is the Army, not McDonald's!"
>
> 「トウキョウナゴヤは[仕事]{しごと}もしないで**ブラブラして**いる。」 = "TokyoNagoya is bumming around all day."

3) When describing a change of state using an onomatopoeia, one would generally need to add a 「に」 instead of a 「と」.

> 「くたくた**に**なるまで[歩]{ある}いた。」 = "I walked until I was pooped."
>
> 「きんきん**に**[冷]{ひ}やしたビールはうまい。」 = "Ice-cold beer tastes good."

Comment: does the distinction between 擬音語 and 擬態語 matter at all?

Comment: So when と is optional for an onomatopeia used adverbially, it's merely a matter of formality whether it should be included or not?

Comment: Do Japanese people really use `鳴く` for dogs instead of `[吠]{ほ}える`?

Comment: Isn't there an exception to the first case when the verb being modified typically takes a quotativeと? Like きっぱり言う, ゆっくり書く?

Answer (score 4):

Chapter 8 of [A Dictionary of Basic Japanese Grammar](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/367611.A_Dictionary_of_Basic_Japanese_Grammar_) explains the と that follows an onomatopoeia.

> "Each sound symbolism is an adverb associated with a specific verb. The adverb is normally followed by the quote marker *to*, because the sound symbolism is perceived as a quotation."

What I am about to write below is purely an inference. I do not have the intuition of a native/fluent speaker, so please take it with a grain of salt. To attempt to answer the question as to what difference the inclusion of と makes, I infer the following from the explanation cited above.

1. Without と, the onomatopoeia is simply an adverb: きらきら光る = to shine sparkingly.
2. The addition of と makes the description more vivid: きらきらと光る = to shine in a "kirakira" way. Somehow the sound symbolism plus the quotation particle と give a more immersive experience as if the reader/hearer imagines seeing the "kirakira" sparkle.