# How is 「と」used in the sentence: 「地震で家がぐらぐらと揺れた。」

Tags: grammar, particle-と, onomatopoeia

The translation I was given for this sentence was: "The house trembled in the earthquake," but I'm at a loss for how 「ぐらぐら」and 「揺れる」are connected by 「と」.

My best guess would be that 「と」functions similarly to "with" to connect the adverb to the verb? In other words, "The house shook uneasily," or something to that effect?

Thank you for your insight!

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/14435/when-is-%e3%81%a8-added-to-onomatopoeia

Answer (score 2):

> How is 「と」used in the sentence: 「地震で家がぐらぐらと揺れた。」

ぐらぐら alone works as an adverb, but we sometimes add と to it for style: そよそよ（と）**そよぐ**風、すやすや（と）**眠る**子ねこ、ばたばた（と）**走りまわる**。
It doesn't really change anything, but seems to add slight explanatory sense that it feels like more care has been taken.

> My best guess would be that 「と」functions similarly to "with" to connect the adverb to the verb? In other words, "The house shook uneasily," or something to that effect?

This usage of **と** is to ***describe*** something, *what* or *how* something is; 「～なんです」と言った。
It indicates the ***content of a quotation or thought or idea*** or the like, and
makes an *adverb phrase or clause*; it's always followed by a verb: と**いう**／と**言う**、と**思って**、頑{がん}と**して**言うことを聞かない