# Can と express a means as well?

Tags: grammar, particle-と, onomatopoeia

For full context:
https://www.satorireader.com/articles/sanzu-no-kawa-episode-1-edition-m?sentenceID=SrOvSLFfSOyCJFzmEmFt

The sentence in question:
朝のまぶしい日差しを受けて、道路わきの林がキラキラとかがやいていた。

My attempt at translation:
"While I was taking the uncomfortable lightrays of the morning, the forest alongside the road did sparkle with sparkling."

What surprises me is that と is used to express a means. I'd usually expect で for this purpose. Are there any conditions to be met so that と can express this?

Comment: "onomatopoeia + と" has been discussed so many times here.  https://japanese.stackexchange.com/search?q=onomatopoeia+%E3%81%A8

Comment: The case "onomatopoeia + verb" is discussed here:
https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/14435/when-is-%e3%81%a8-added-to-onomatopoeia

However, the answer there says that in the case "onomatopoeia + verb" the use of と is considered "inappropriate". So what shall I make of my case above now?^^

Comment: According to the answer, と is inappropriate when an onomatopoeia is used with する, not every verb. See the first case.