# Why is there a と in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, parsing

The following sentence is from the book コンビニ人間:

> 家族はだんだん**と**不安になったようだ。

My question is: what is the role of **と** here? How would the meaning change if this **と** were omitted? I can't seem to find any grammar point on this usage.

Comment: Onomatopoeia can often take と. Related [When is と added to onomatopoeia?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/14435)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 「だんだんと不安になった」

and

> 「だんだん不安になった」

have the exact same meaning. と can be stuck to the end of certain adverbs （ゆっくりと、黙々と、次々と、のんびりと etc）. Depending on the usage it can make the sentence sound slightly more formal / higher register or place slightly more emphasis on the adverb in question, but ultimately has no real effect on the actual meaning of the sentence.

Answer (score 1):

Hi and welcome to JPStackexchange!

According to https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%A0%E3%82%93%E3%81%A0%E3%82%93%E3%81%A8

**だんだんと**　is "an expression that means that the degree of something changes or progresses gradually, little by little, in order. An **adverb** that modifies a verb."

CollinsDictionary translates だんだんと as "slowly" and だんだん as "gradually, increasingly", so I think だんだんと is not as strong in the gradual increase.

(Nice book recommendation by the way!)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My understanding is that だんだん is also an adverb meaning gradually, little by little, etc. But I don't know why the と is included here. The book is indeed very interesting.