# What does this と do?

Tags: grammar, particle-と

For full context:
https://www3.nhk.or.jp/news/html/20180125/k10011302761000.html

The sentence in question:
高さが１３３メートルある「那智の滝」は、那智勝浦町にある熊野那智大社のご神体とされています。

My attempt at translation:
"Concerning the nachifalls with a height of 133meters, they are made (together) with "Kumano Nachi Taisha" which is Nachikatsuura."

Obviously, the way I interpreted と here doesnt make much sense. But I simply have no idea what it is supposed to do there.

Comment: Or more generally: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/35982/what-does-%e3%81%a8-in-%e5%af%be%e8%b1%a1%e3%81%a8%e3%81%99%e3%82%8b-mean

Comment: Even more generally: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/55169/5010

Comment: Thanks! :=) So does "...熊野那智大社のご神体とされています" mean "...is regarded as the shintai of 熊野那智大社"?

Comment: @Narktor Yes, that's right :)