# What does this となった express?

Tags: grammar

For full context, see [here](https://www3.nhk.or.jp/news/html/20180125/k10011302761000.html).

The sentence in question:

> 厳しい冷え込み**となった**２５日朝、滝つぼが一面凍りついた**ほか**、流れ落ちる滝の周りにはつららができていて、岩場が氷で白く染まっていました。

I already posted a fairly similar question [here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/56250/what-does-this-%e3%81%a8-do?noredirect=1#comment97449_56250).

But I cant really find out how to apply the regularities lined out in the answers can be applied to なる here.
So basically, I dont know how と in 厳しい冷え込み**と**なった２５日朝 is used here. I also don't really know what to do with ほか in 滝つぼが一面凍りついた**ほか**.

My attempt at translation:

> "There was intense cooldown on the 25th morning, and one side of the waterfall basin froze over (ほか???) and concerning in the surroundings of the waterfall, there appeared icicles and the rocky area was dyed white."

To make this translation, I just jused "and" constructions to cover the parts I didnt understand, but I would definitely like to know how these parts work ^^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd like to answer just the question about ほか. I assume you're familiar with the clause-initial phrase/word そのほか, meaning "aside from/in addition to that..." (If not, here are [examples on Jisho](http://jisho.org/search/%E3%81%9D%E3%81%AE%E3%81%BB%E3%81%8B%E3%80%80%23sentences).)

The usage in your example in the same, except that the pronoun その is replaced by a concrete phrase. In short, Aほか、B means "Aside from A, B." This can be a disjunctive meaning ("Aside from the fire, it was a great party.") but it doesn't have to be, and it this case it isn't.