# Why is と used in this sentence?

Tags: particles

This sentence translation is given as: He has been asked to sit on the committee. I can see the meaning, except with the と after ように. Can anyone explain why　と is used in here?

彼はその委員会のメンバーになるようにと依頼を受けてきてきた。

Comment: `受けてきてきた` Is it not 受けてきて**い**た or something?

Comment: Related (or duplicate?): https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/2666/9831

Comment: @Chocolate I agree with your link.  But I'm also wondering whether there's any resource more specific to the use of **[verb]ようにと** followed by a verb of making a request or giving an order....  I just feel that particular link is a bit weak on explaining this particular usage.

Comment: Does this maybe have the right words for a good explanation? Try searching "youni" --> [Jgram](http://jgram.org/pages/viewList.php)

Comment: I think the title should be edited to "Meaning of [verb]ようにと in requests, admonitions, and commands" and a more fully fleshed out explanation be provided than that in the currently linked answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could parse it this way:

> 彼は『その委員会のメンバーになるように』**と**依頼を受けてきていた

The と is quotative.

ように is the continuative form of the auxiliary ようだ.　According to [デジタル大辞泉](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/226613/meaning/m0u/):

> ようだ［助動］
>   ５ （「ように」の形で）婉曲 (えんきょく) な命令・希望の意を表す。「開始時刻に遅れない**ように**」「今後ともよろしくご指導くださいます**ように**」

ように can express 婉曲な(softer/roundabout) 命令・希望(order/command or hope).

So your sentence can be interpreted as literally saying:

"He was requested, (saying) 'Be a member of that committee' and was there."

Hence "He was there, requested to be a member of that committee."

(≂ 彼はその委員会のメンバーになってくださいと依頼を受けてきていた）

Examples:

> - 今日中に報告書を仕上げる**ようにと**指示を受けた。
> - 海に近づかない**ようにと**注意された。

Answer (score 1):

> > 彼はその委員会のメンバーになるようにと依頼を受けてきてきた。
>
> This sentence translation is given as: He has been asked to sit on the committee.
> Can anyone explain why　と is used in here?

This その委員会のメンバーになるように is the ***content*** of the request (依頼{いらい}). This could be even clearer if it's メンバーになるように**という**依頼を受けてきた.

Without the と, it becomes unclear.

> 彼はその委員会のメンバーになるように  依頼を受けてきていた。

The ように starts to sound like ために or なれるように. It's vague and hard to process, but could sound like the becoming the member is not the content of the request but is his reason why he's received the request.

The phrase その委員会のメンバーになるようにと（いう）should be taken as an appositive to 依頼, not the reason of receiving the request.

---

I find if it's な**れる**ようにと依頼を受けてきた, the content of quotation becomes a wish, and because of the nature of wish, it works with or without と; it can be expressed as either the *reason* or the *content* of the wish.

Comment: Ambiguousなのはむしろ「ように と 依頼を」の方じゃないですか？

Comment: えっと、もう少し詳しく書いてもらえませんか？He has been asked to sit on the committee. と訳語も提供されているわけですが、「ようにと」のほうが「ように」より問題があるということですか？

Comment: まず、「ようにと」は基本的に「ように依頼を受けた」と同じだが一方で依頼の内容を表しているとも解釈できるということです。

Comment: 前者の「と」は「東へ」→「東へと」みたいなもの。コメ分けてすみません。

Comment: @user4092 As I've stated above, ようにという依頼を受け is the clearest, ようにと依頼を受け is not bad, but ように依頼を受け is unclear.